# Battle Rope Workouts

Tags: weight-loss, cardio

There are two Battle Rope workouts I plan to do in the same session:

- (Workout #1) An HIIT workout as explained [here](http://onnit.com/academy/fat-burning-battle-ropes-hiit-workout).
- (Workout #2) Strengthening the core by isolating it using [these routines](http://youtube.com/watch?v=FyGBSs1X1qM).

What are the benefits? What size of battle rope is good for cardio training? (I was considering the Onnit battle rope but it seems very light - starting from 24lbs.)

Comment: What will your cardio sessions look like more specifically? How will you incorporate battle ropes into them?

Comment: There are two workouts I plan to do in the same session: (Workout #1) An HIIT workout as explained here: https://www.onnit.com/academy/fat-burning-battle-ropes-hiit-workout  and (Workout #2) Strengthen the core by isolate it using the following routines : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FyGBSs1X1qM